# Apache server no working (ubuntu 16.04, lamp server)

Tags: php, apache, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
     [....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for    
     apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error   
     code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
     details.
     failed!
     techadon@techadon-M68MT-D3:~$ sudo systemctl status apache2.service

apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
     Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-10-01 11:48:31 SAST;  
     1min 3
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
     Process: 4128 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, 
     status=0/SUCCESS
     Process: 636 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, 
     status=0/SUCC
     Process: 4154 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited,   
     status=1/FAILU

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]:  *
Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]:  * The apache2 configtest faile

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]: Output of config test was:
Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]: apache2: Syntax error on line 2

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 apache2[4154]: The Apache error log may have m

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process e

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web s

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered fail

Oct 01 11:48:31 techadon-M68MT-D3 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with resul
lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

Comment: i started by installing each module but it still gave me this error

Comment: every time after the installation of phpmyadmin and thn including " include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf" in he apache configuration file. if i try to restart it gives me an error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: MAy be the use of command `apache2ctl configtest` can help...

Answer (score 0):

Your apache configuration is wrong. Check it and restart apache.

Comment: so what should i do. should i purge it and install again. i did that like 5 times

Comment: If your configuration is wrong it won't fix it reinstalling. Check apache configuration in /etc/apache2 and give a look also at [how to configure apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps)